# Bootstrap - class row not working well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I published my application in a server and for a specific user the fields are not in better layout, as the picture bellow:

[image]

The yellow area is getting empty and breaking to a new line.

My code is:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Período</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parametros.DT_INICIO, new { @id = "txt-dtInicio", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">Até</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parametros.DT_FIM, new { @id = "txt-dtFim", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Equipamento</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Parametros.COD_EQPMT_PRODC, Model.ListaEquipamentos, "Selecione o equipamento", new { @id = "ddl-Equipamento", @class = "form-control input-sm selectpicker", data_live_search = "true" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Tipo Aço</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parametros.COD_TIPO_ACO, new { @id = "txt-Tipo-Aco", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "5" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Grupo</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Parametros.GRUPO_PROAC, Model.ListaGrupos, "", new { @id = "ddl-Grupo", @class = "form-control input-sm"})
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Truno</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Parametros.TUR_FIM_PROCE, Model.ListaTurnos, "", new { @id = "ddl-Turno", @class = "form-control input-sm"})
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>U.M.</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parametros.COD_IDENT_UNMET, new { @id = "txt-UM", @class = "form-control input-sm", @maxlength = "12" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Espessura Inicial</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parametros.ESP_MM_INI, new { @id = "txt-Esp-Inicial", @class = "form-control input-sm"})
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Espessura Final</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parametros.ESP_MM_FIM, new { @id = "txt-Esp-Final", @class = "form-control input-sm"})
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>T3</label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Parametros.T3, new { @id = "txt-T3", @class = "form-control input-sm"})
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Im my computer, for example, the screen is rendered correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yellow gap is due to a height difference, not because you have more than 12 column units.

The [uneven break that's causing the gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572753/bootstrap-3-fluid-grid-layout-issues/19573033) happens when the contents of the the `col-*` vary in height. **It's fine to use more than 12 col units** in a single `.row` element as long as you understand the extra `col-*` will [wrap to a new line](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

I see that you're using `selectpicker` and it may be causing that select element to become a different height than the other `form-control` inputs. I was not able to recreate this with standard inputs. Check for other CSS that maybe causing the `col-*` to become different heights.

http://www.codeply.com/go/SV2tXWa2BF

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I also could not simulate this on my computer. I'll check the CSS of the selectpicker