# Bootstrap grid-system 2 items in xs screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

I have the following grid-system, they're 3 rows and in each row there is 3 items in large screen, i want to edit the code so that they become 2 items in each column in xs screen but they become missed up, how can i do that?

```html
<div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="service1.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>Desktop & Mobile Website Design</h5>
                            <p>We offer a full website planning, workshop and design service for all industry sectors. We are also experts at creating websites for mobile phones and tablet devices.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="web-cms.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>Website & Content Management</h5>
                            <p>All websites need intelligence, and we have many years experience blending design and content management systems to help bring your website to life.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="graphic-design.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>Creative Branding & Graphic Design</h5>
                            <p>Effective branding and engaging graphic design is the first thing your clients notice. Make sure you stand out from the crowd with some high impact visuals.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="programming.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>Web Applications & Programming</h5>
                            <p>We are experience at integrating technical applications and web systems. Make sure your business is supported correctly and your operations work together seamlessly.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="ecommerce.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>e-Commerce & Payment Solutions</h5>
                            <p>We can help you trade online with full e-commerce solutions comprising hundreds of products or maybe a simple payment gateway to accept customers transactions.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="domains.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>Domain Names & Website Hosting</h5>
                            <p>Professional websites require a solid platform. We manage hundreds of domain names and also run Dedicated and Cloud based hosting solutions for our clients.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="enewsletters.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>e-Newsletters & Broadcasting</h5>
                            <p>We have years of experience helping customers market their business to interested people. We can help you design, build and broadcast your email campaigns.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="marketing.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>Social Media & Marketing</h5>
                            <p>Social media is part of everyday life and having an overall strategy is crucial for the success of your online business. We can help you get the most from your activity.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"> <img src="content.jpg" style="height:100px">
                            <h5>Content Creation & Production</h5>
                            <p>We can work with you to help you with your copywriting, photography and video production in case you can’t create these assets yourself.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: have you tried changing `'col-xs-4'` to `'col-xs-6'`?

Comment: @john_h i did, but they don't appear the way i want, a gap appears in each row i dont know why

Comment: Ok. Bootstrap classes will have properties inherent, such as `padding, margin, etc`.  You want no spacing in between the divs when it is xs screen?  You can remove the padding in your own CSS: `col-xs-6: margin: 0; padding: 0;` Does that get it closer to what you are looking for?  Also, row will have properties that are inherited from child elements.

Comment: Are the images/content in the columns making them different height? If so you need to use clearfix or responsive resets every X number of `col-`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19573033/171456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 3 items across on `lg` and 2 items across on `xs` you must use **column wrapping** and **responsive resets**. *All* of the `col-` should be in a single `.row`...

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 1 </div> 
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 2 </div> 
      <!-- clearfix xs cols every 2 -->
      <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div> 
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 3 </div> 
      <!-- clearfix lg cols every 3 -->
      <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div> 
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 4 </div> 
       <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div> 
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 5 </div> 
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 6 </div>
       <div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-lg"></div>  
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 7 </div> 
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 8 </div>
       <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>  
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"> 9 </div> 
     ...
</div>
```