# Problem with spacing between two rows - HTML template

Tags: html, css, display, spacing

I am having a issue with spacing between two rows/elements in a HTML template. I am trying to create a grid for the products in our restaurant and downloaded a template from the Internet. As you can see in this picture:
[issue1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOvNi.png)

I am having issues with spacing between the first line and second line elements when trying to add a new row into the text. The rows were added with the p element and when doing that, the whole entire 2nd row just goes down by so much space.

This is the HTML i'm using (issue version vs. non-issue version)

```
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="single-best-receipe-area mb-30">
                    <img src="https://www.coopathome.ch/img/produkte/880_880/RGB/4798850_001.jpg?_=1527527264626" width=290px height=304px alt="" class="center-block" />
                    <div class="receipe-content">
                            <h5 style="line-height: 0px;">Barilla - Penne Rigate fără gluten 400g</h5> <p style="color:#ff9400; text-decoration: line-through;" >14,00 RON</p> <p style="color:#ff9400; line-height: 0px;"> REDUCERE 10% - 12,00 RON</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Single Best Receipe Area -->
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="single-best-receipe-area mb-30" >
                    <img src="https://www.coopathome.ch/img/produkte/880_880/RGB/4798854_001.jpg?_=1505902808944" width=320px height=304px alt="" class="center-block" />
                    <div class="receipe-content">
                        <a href="receipe-post.html">
                            <h5>Barilla - Spaghetti fără gluten 400g</h5>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And below is the custom CSS I've added:

```
.single-best-receipe-area .receipe-content {
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
.mb-30 {
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.receipe-content {
line-height: 0px;
}
```

As you can see, I've tried what I found here on stackoverflow with using line-height:0px but with no succes.
I am not web developer unfortunately and just trying to create a menu list for our restaurant. Help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you!

EDIT: Demo with code: http://hanulsiminica.ro/test/menu.html

EDIT2: More representative image of the issue: [issue2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJKmF.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a working snippet or jsfiddle for regenerate your problem

Comment: I added a demo with the whole code here since it's a whole template and JSFiddle might not be really the best solution for that: http://hanulsiminica.ro/test/menu.html

Comment: This is an issue with bootstrap 3 grid try  solutions like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572753/bootstrap-3-fluid-grid-layout-issues

Comment: Thank you Nidhi! Using the solution here:  https://www.codeply.com/go/zNCNrNPb9f worked. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using just the code you've provided, changing the html to this to add a 'flex-height' class to the first div with current class of 'row':

```
<div class="row flex-height">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="single-best-receipe-area mb-30">
                        <img src="https://www.coopathome.ch/img/produkte/880_880/RGB/4798850_001.jpg?_=1527527264626" width=290px height=304px alt="" class="center-block" />
                        <div class="receipe-content">
                                <h5>Barilla - Penne Rigate fără gluten 400g</h5> <p style="color:#ff9400; text-decoration: line-through;" >14,00 RON</p> <p style="color:#ff9400;"> REDUCERE 10% - 12,00 RON</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Single Best Receipe Area -->
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="single-best-receipe-area mb-30" >
                        <img src="https://www.coopathome.ch/img/produkte/880_880/RGB/4798854_001.jpg?_=1505902808944" width=320px height=304px alt="" class="center-block" />
                        <div class="receipe-content">
                            <a href="receipe-post.html">
                                <h5>Barilla - Spaghetti fără gluten 400g</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS to this:

```
.single-best-receipe-area{
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  padding-top:20px;
}
.receipe-content{
  padding-top:30px;
}
.row.flex-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.flex-height > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Gives a better looking result. JSFiddle example here (try resizing your browser too, to see how it looks on smaller and larger screens) - [New JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MattRey/us0vj7Lf/29/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for trying to help! I have tried your solution, but nothing changed. My issue is, as shown in the image I posted, the huge vertical gap between the product lines when adding new text using the p tag. When using just the h5 tag for 1 line of text, everything is fine, but when I try to add new text using the p tag the row below automatically creates that huge gap. EDIT: Added new image at bottom of main post with issue.

Comment: Great solution from Nidhi - updated my JSFiddle but would vote up Nidhi's answer if I could!

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
  .single-best-receipe-area .receipe-content {
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to help. Added the CSS but still not working, nothing changed. Might it be because I'm using the p tag? Do I have an alternative solution? EDIT: Added demo link.

Answer (score -1):

.card-img{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Barilla - Penne Rigate fără gluten 400g 14,00 RON  REDUCERE 10% - 12,00 RON
                    
                
            

            
            
                
                    
                    
                        
                            Barilla - Spaghetti fără gluten 400g
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                    
                        
                            Barilla - Spaghetti fără gluten 400g