# Boostrap 3 Fluid Grid Layout Issue; Long items cause stacking problems

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is very similar to [Bootstrap 3 fluid grid layout issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572753/bootstrap-3-fluid-grid-layout-issues) and [Bootstrap responsiveness view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569235/bootstrap-responsiveness-view) but the options for masonry and isotope, while attractive, aren't an option as I **must retain ordering** for the elements.

From the linked questions, I've moved a fair bit of the way forward using the clearfix class application as can be seen at http://bootply.com/103688. The clearfix divs are left unindented so they stand out more.

I also found that undesirable results will occur if, as is my case, I am only using some of the column sizes (xs, md, lg). This necessitates that the clearfix also specify the visible-sm or, when the viewport reaches the "small" size, the clearfix is no longer visible, and problematic stacking recurs.

Applying them is simple enough, as this is a real-world fizzbuzz problem, but it seems anti-DRY. Is there a cleaner way for me to do this, with less repetition of the clearfix tags? Some means of having the browser (CSS) compute where the clearfix should be applied?

Comment: No solution short of keeping them all the same height with overflow hidden or some jquery solution that gets them all equal height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an manual approach of creating rows according with the number of elements per breaking point. For example:

If you have a row with 2 elements only:

```
@media(max-width: @screen-tablet){
    // create rows (clearfix)
    .col-xs-6:nth-of-type(odd){ clear:left; }
}
```

or if your rows contains 4 elements

```
@media(min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-desktop){
    // create rows (clearfix)
    .col-sm-4:nth-of-type(3n+1){ clear:left; }
}
```

etc..